# Capture string that can match several patterns

Tags: java, regex

I have two types of strings:

```
1) "bla bla <a>interesting</a> bla bzzz"
2) "bla bla <b>interesting bla bzzz"
```

What I need is to capture the "interesting" substring, preferably using one pattern.

So far I have

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<a>(.*?)</a>)|(<b>(.*?))");
    String message = "bzzzzzz <a>AaA</a>efwef<b>BbB";

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
        }
    }
}
```

The result I would like is

```
AaA
BbB
```

But instead I'm getting

```
<a>AaA</a>
AaA
null
null
null
null
<b>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: r u using any library for matching?

Comment: Are the number `1)` `2)` part of your string?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions! Use a DOM parser.

Comment: @DuncanJones: It's going to be tricky to work with the `<b>` tag.

Comment: I think this belongs here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1907906

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regular expressions! Use a DOM parser.

Comment: @NK123: Just java.util.regex

Comment: @nhahtdh: No, just the string within the double quotes

Comment: @DuncanJones: Thanks for the hint. But I just need to use regex in this case.

Comment: The parenthesis you are using around you two `|`:ed expressions counts as captures....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<b>(.*?)
```

will always match `<b>` and nothing else because `.*?` matches the empty string and doesn't try to match more than that if it doesn't have to. Also, your regex has way more capturing parentheses than you need.

Try

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a>(.*?)</a>|<b>(\\S*)");
```

The second half of this pattern matches a sequence of non-whitespace characters (`\S`) after `<b>`.

Comment: Just to add: some checks are needed to figure out which one to print as output.

Comment: Thanks Tim! That solves my major issue. Still between the AaA and BbB are 2 nulls, but I can live with that. Thanks

Comment: @RadekS: Those nulls come from the fact that only one of the alternatives can match, but you're iterating over both capturing groups, one of which will therefore always not have participated in the match.